# TFS not always emailing pull request notifications

Tags: tfs

I have a project in TFS.  The last two pull requests, we got emails for "xxx has approved the code" but not the subsequent emails for "xxx marked the pull request as completed" The pull requests in question were both approved and completed.  The emails do not appear to have been caught in Outlook's spam filter.

The subscription for all projects is "A pull request I created or am a reviewer on is updated"

Version: 15.117.26714.0

Is there a way to diagnose why TFS email notifications are so flaky?  This isn't the first complaint I've gotten about TFS email notifications being unreliable.

Comment: Could not reproduce my side with  same TFS  version 15.117.26714.0. Did this occurs on all of your pull requests or just some specific?

Answer (score 0):

Have tested  TFS 2017.2 instance but could not reproduce the issue on my side. Both approved and completed E-mail sent correctly.

So the issue seems not be able to stable reproduce. For now, there is no way to trouble shoot this directly. You could check the event log in TFS sever to see if you got any error or warning info there.

To narrow down the issue, you could analysis both address the E-mail achieved and sent.

- Notifications are sent to your preferred email address, which you can
  [change from your account preference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/notifications/change-email-address)s. Change the preferred one
  and use another to see if issue still exists.
- The received notifications are sent by the [configured SMTP
  server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-customize-alerts). Try to specify another SMTP Server and the email address
  to use for sending emails.

One possibility for this issue, the action of approved and completed pull request were too closely. This may cause TFS only trigger one E-Mail. Do it slowly and try  again.  Based on my testing, in this case, the E-Mail are sent not in sequence, the completed came first then the approved one.

Moreover, you could also explicitly add a subscription with "*A pull request I created or am a reviewer on is updated*" just for the project you are working on, which may do the trick.